Arm twists too much even with twist bones
I've followed a tutorial for wrist rotation, but the mesh still pinches itself when I rotate the hand :[.


Here's the tutorial I've followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P81DGubVILA
I have no idea how to fix it. Maybe bendy bones?
Edit: .blend file:


hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

I added the .blend file in the post

The topology is pretty bad, you should retopologize, that said the problem comes from bad weight, for example you have enable the Deform option of this bone when it should be deactivated:

On the opposite you have disabled the option for this bone when it should be activated:

You could simply select the armature, shift select the object, switch it to Weight Paint mode, select these 3 bones and Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones:


That works, thank you!
